# how to Render multi language HTML String into PDF using iText's HTMLWorker class

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

MY HTML string sometime having Chinese words and my code shows Blank space at the place of chinese words

Here is my HTML looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<table  border='1'  align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='left' width='60%'><font size='2'><b>Answer choices</b></td>
<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='center' width='20%'><font size='2'><b>Percentage</b></td>
<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d'  align='center' width='20%' ><font size='2'><b>Responses</b></div></td>
</tr>
</div>
</td>
<td  align='left' ><div>紅</div></td>
<td align='center' ><div >66.67%</div></td>
<td  align='center'><div >2</div></td><
/tr>
</div>
</td>
<td  align='left' ><div>黃</div></td>
<td align='center' ><div >66.67%</div></td>
<td  align='center'><div >2</div></td>
</tr>
</div>
</td>
<td  align='left' ><div>粉紅</div></td>
<td align='center' ><div >33.33%</div></td>
<td  align='center'><div >1</div></td>
</tr>
</div>
</td>
<td  align='left' ><div>藍</div></td>
<td align='center' ><div >33.33%</div></td>
<td  align='center'><div >1</div></td>
</tr>
</div>
</td>
<td  align='left' ><div>綠</div></td>
<td align='center' ><div >0.0%</div></td>
<td  align='center'><div >0</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' ></td>
<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='right' ><font size='2'><i><b>Total</b></i></td>
<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='center' >3</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code to parse this above string is

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
    String startstr = "<div>"
            +"<table  border='1'  align='center' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>"
            +"<tr>"
            +"<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='left' width='60%'><font size='2'><b>Answer choices</b></td>"
            +"<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='center' width='20%'><font size='2'><b>Percentage</b></td>"
            +"<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d'  align='center' width='20%' ><font size='2'><b>Responses</b></div></td>"
            +"</tr>";
    String endString="<tr>"
            +"<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' ></td>"
            +"<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='right' ><font size='2'><i><b>Total</b></i></td>"
            +"<td  bgcolor= '#d1eb9d' align='center' >";
    String finalString= "</td>"
                        +"</tr>"
                        +"</table>"
                        +"</div>";
    sb.append(startstr);
     int sum=0;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> queMap1 : qvo.getResponseMap().entrySet()){
            String value=queMap1.getValue();
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////System.out.println("type of question in gettable"+qvo.getType());
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> queMap1 : qvo.getResponseMap().entrySet()){

        String key=queMap1.getKey();
        String value=queMap1.getValue();
        String[] splitarr= key.split(",");
        String type= qvo.getType();
        sb.append("</div></td>");
        sb.append("<td  align='left' ><div>");
            if(surveyType.equalsIgnoreCase("singlesurvey")){
                sb.append(splitarr[2]);
            }else sb.append(splitarr[0]);
        sb.append("</div></td>");
        sb.append("<td align='center' ><div >");
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("M") || type.equalsIgnoreCase("P")){
            sum=Integer.parseInt(surveyNumberResponses);
        }
        double percent=getPercentage(value,String.valueOf(sum));
        sb.append(String.valueOf(percent)+"%");
        sb.append("</div></td>");

        // response
        sb.append("<td  align='center'><div >");
        sb.append(value);
        sb.append("</div></td>");
        sb.append("</tr>");

    }
    sb.append(endString);
    sb.append(String.valueOf(sum));
    sb.append(finalString);
     try {
        htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(sb.toString()));
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

above code can render english language properly and shows blank space in the place of chinese words

image for english language looks like this

[image]

image for chinese language looks like this
[image]

Please suggest me how to show chinese words in available in HTML String in PDF i m using iText api for creating PDF

update

now i am using this code to parse above string Still showing blank space

```
String  ttfFontName=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ARIALUNI.TTF";
    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
             XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
             fontImp.register(ttfFontName);
             FontFactory.setFontImp(fontImp);
             InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
             worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is,null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);
```

Please please help me Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are using `HTMLWorker`: abandon all hope or start using [XML Worker](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml). `HTMLWorker` has been replaced by XML Worker many years ago!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Is it not possible with HTMLWorker ? if not then would u please suggest me how to do with XML Worker?

Comment: Did you click on [the link I provided](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml)? It gives you plenty of Q&A examples like [How to make Cyrillic characters display properly when converting HTML to PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-make-cyrillic-characters-display-properly-when-converting-html-pdf) Take a look at the pages tagged [languages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/languages) There are many [XML Worker examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker) on the site.

Comment: Specific Asian examples are [D07_ParseHtmlAsian](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#712-d07_parsehtmlasian.java), [D07bis_ParseHtmlAsian](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#713-d07bis_parsehtmlasian.java), and [D07tris_ParseHtmlAsian](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#714-d07tris_parsehtmlasian.java). The resources used for these examples can be found [on the same page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples#720-hero.html).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie sorry may be my question is trivial but I went through ParseHtml2.java my problem is my Chinese word are not in Unicode character that's why may be code available in ParseHtml2.java is not working  i have update my question also with code Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **BrunoLowagie** finally I got the solution of the problem. As I edited above in my question that after using **XMLWorkerHelper** my PDF still showing blank space at the place of Chinese word it was because i have not specified the font (that I register for the **XMLWorkerFontProvider** object)  in the style tag in my HTML code. now the HTML code will look like this

```
String str="<html><head>"
            + "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8\"/>"
            + "</head>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<div>"
            + "<table  border='1'  align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td  style='background-color:#d1eb9d;'  align='left' width='40%'><font size='3'><b>Answer choices</b></font></td>"
            + "<td  style='background-color:#d1eb9d; ' align='center' width='20%'><font size='3'><b>Percentage</b></font></td>"
            + "<td  style='background-color:#d1eb9d; '  align='center' width='20%' ><font size='3'><b>Responses</b></font></td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td  style=\"font-family: arial unicode ms, ARIALUNI; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal;\" align='left' ><div>藍</div></td>"
            + "<td style='text-align:center;' ><div >66.67%</div></td>"
            + "<td  style='text-align:center;'><div >2</div></td></tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td  style=\"font-family: arial unicode ms, ARIALUNI; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal;\" align='left' ><div>粉紅</div></td>"
            + "<td style='text-align:center;' ><div >66.67%</div></td>"
            + "<td  style='text-align:center;' ><div >2</div></td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td  style=\"font-family: arial unicode ms, ARIALUNI; fkont-size:16px; font-weight: normal;\" align='left' ><div>apple</div></td>"
            + "<td style='text-align:center;' ><div >33.33%</div></td>"
            + "<td  style='text-align:center;'><div >1</div></td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td  style=\"font-family: arial unicode ms, ARIALUNI; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal;\" align='left' ><div>紅</div></td>"
            + "<td style='text-align:center;' ><div >33.33%</div></td>"
            + "<td  style='text-align:center;'><div >1</div></td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td  align='left' style=\"font-family: arial unicode ms, ARIALUNI; font-size:16px; font-weight: normal;\" ><div>綠</div></td>"
            + "<td style='text-align:center;' ><div >0.0%</div></td>"
            + "<td  style='text-align:center;'><div >0</div></td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
            + "<td style='background-color:#d1eb9d;' ></td>"
            + "<td  style='background-color:#d1eb9d;' align='right' ><font size='3'><i><b>Total</b></i></font></td>"
            + "<td  style='background-color:#d1eb9d;' align='center' >3</td></tr>"
            + "</table>"
            + "</div>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";
```

and Java code will look like this

```
String  ttfFileName=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ARIALUNI.TTF";
 XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
         XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
         fontImp.register(ttfFileName);
         FontFactory.setFontImp(fontImp);
         InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
         worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is,null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);
```

Now the table is looking like this [image]

Thank you hopfully this post help others.